# Comparing a char variable to empty char does not work

Tags: compare, character, pascal

Say `x` is a character.
Whenever I do `if(x <> '')` to know whether the variable is empty or not, it just does not work.
However, when I attempt to do this `if(x <> chr(0))`, it does work.
I have tried the same thing on two versions of the compiler :  Free Pascal and Charm Pascal, but I am still facing the same problem.

Comment: '' is a string with a length of 0. There is no character. None. A[ny] character is not equal to the absence of a character.

Comment: You are confusing Chars and Strings.  A String can be empty (zero length) whereas a Char is always one character in size.

Comment: Got it, so whenever I compare strings, I should use ORD or CHR, right?

Comment: Nope, you use Ord and Chr on chars, not strings.

Comment: A string is not a character. Compare the same types: a character to a character (perhaps a character in a string), a string to a string (perhaps after converting a character to a string).

Comment: compare characters* sorry for the mistake.

Comment: It is not necessary to include the tag information in the title as well. The tag system here works extremely well, and it does not need additional help from you. Please don't get into that habit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as an "empty char". The `Char` type is always a single character.

That character could be 1 byte `AnsiChar` representing a value from `0..255`. (In Delphi and fpc, it could also be a 2 byte `WideChar` representing a value from `0..65535`.) Either way it is always represented as `'<something>'`. That "something" must be a character value.

When you compare `x <> Chr(0)` you are taking the *byte value* of `0` and converting it to a `Char` so a valid comparison can be performed.

---

## Side Notes

For `Char` to *reliably* have the concept "no value" requires storing additional information. E.g. Databases may have a *hidden internal* bit field indicating the value is `NULL`. It's important to be aware that this is *fundamentally different* from any of the valid values it may have if it's not `NULL`. Libraries that interact with databases need to provide a way to determine if a value is `NULL`.

You haven't provided any information about the actual problem you're trying to solve but here are some thoughts that may yield progress:

- If you're dealing with user input, it may be more appropriate to compare with a space character `' '`.
- If you're dealing with characters read from a file, you should probably be checking number of bytes/characters actually read.
- If you're trying to determine the end of a string it's much more reliable to use the `Length()` of the string.

  - (Though there are some environments that use the convention of treating `Char(0)` as a special character meaning "end-of-string".) But the convention requires allocating *an extra character* making the string internally longer than its text length. So the technique **is not usable** if the environment doesn't support it.
- Most importantly, from comments it seems you might be struggling with the difference between *empty-string* and how that's represented as a `Char`. And the point is that **it isn't**. You need to check the length of the string.

E.g. You can do the following:

```
if (s <> '') then
begin
  { You now know there is at least 1 character in the string so
    you can safely read it and not worry about "if it has a value".}
  x := s[1];
  ...
end;
```